# Yarn - install specific tag from gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, yarnpkg

I'm trying to migrate from npm to yarn, to be able to use the .lock file but I'm having serious difficulties to specify a version of one of the dependancies that we are using. When trying to specify it like this:

```
git+http://gitlab.local.fb/project/name.git#1.0.0
```

it returns the following error:

> Refusing to download the git repo 
>   "http://gitlab.local.fb/project/name.git" over HTTP without a
>   commit hash

Adding it via

```
yarn add git+http://gitlab.local.fb/project/name.git#1.0.0
```

returns the same error.

Specifying it with the commit version seems to work, but it's really strange to require it, instead of the human-readable tags of versions. Am I doing something wrong or Yarn doesn't support this functionality for gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

Update 2018: With an updated yarn, you can do `yarn` or `yarn install` and it works with depencencies written on long form (private git repos):

`"my-repo": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/my-user-or-group-name/my-repo.git#tag-or-commitish",`

Careful with `git+ssh` vs `ssh+git` - one works, the other not -- even though git would understand it.

The short form
`"my-repo": "gitlab:my-user-or-group-name/my-repo#tag-or-commitish",`
might not be fully functional - there are bugs tracking this.

The `#tag-or-commitish` part can be a branch like `#production` or a tag `#v1.0.1`, etc.

Example, if your private repo package is published as `@foo/bar`:

1. `yarn remove @foo/bar`
2. `yarn add @foo/bar@git+ssh://git@gitlab.your_domain.net:your-user-group-name/foo.git#branch-name`